# Married two sisters before accepting Islam. What should be done?

Tags: sunni, nikah

I had met and married a woman, after 8 years I felt I have something for her sister. Then we agreed with my wife and her that we should marry. And we did it.

Then later we discovered it's a haram to marry two sisters.

But it was too late, so what does Islam instruct us to do in this regard?

Comment: who read your nikah and who were the witnesses?

Comment: _"Then we agreed with my wife and her we should marry."_ I wish at least I could imagine this situation :)

Comment: @Zia that doesn't  matter, as that was before accepting Islam.

Comment: @MAKZ The point is that in body of the question OP doesn't specify or even hint to the fact that they did this before converting to Islam. Although the a title says so but instead of elaborating the situation further OP totally skipped it. @ OP Welcome to [islam.se] and please elaborate the situation.

Answer (score 4):

[There is a hadith](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/13/69) in *Sunan Abi Dawud* that describes the same situation as yours.

***Al-Dahhak b. Firuz*** reported on the authority of his father:

> I said: Messenger of Allah, I have embraced Islam and two sisters are my wives. He replied: **Divorce any one of them you wish**.

<sup>grade:[hasan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasan_%28hadith%29#.E1.B8.A4asan)</sup>

There is no mention of punishment or any reprimand in the situation given in the hadith. Moreover, Allah always accepts repentance for mistakes done in ignorance [[1](http://quran.com/6/54), [2](http://quran.com/7/153)].

But you are required divorce any of them. There is no rule as to which one to chose, so keep the one that you love more.